# mysql select data from 3 tables using user input

Tags: mysql, input

I have 3 tables with the following columns and values (they have multiple entries but I'm showing you one):

`protein`

```
 +--------+------+-------------+
 | pdb_id | name | description |
 +--------+------+-------------+
 | 1AF6   | porin| maltoporin  |
 +--------+------+-------------+
```

`organism`:

```
 +--------+-----------------------+
 | org_id | organismName          |
 +--------+-----------------------+
 | 4      | Comamonas acidovorans |
 +--------+-----------------------+
```

`protein_organism`:

```
 +--------+--------+
 | pdb_id | org_id | 
 +--------+--------+
 | 1AF6   | 4      |
 +--------+--------+
```

I'm making a website where someone can see all the proteins from a specific organism that can be selected from a drop down menu.
However when I try to fetch the data the browser goes to the correct url: `http://localhost:8084/response_organism?organismName=Comamonas+acidovorans`
but shows nothing.
This is my sql command:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM protein JOIN protein_organism ON protein_organism.pdb_id = protein.pdb_id JOIN organism ON organism.org_id = protein_organism.org_id WHERE organism.organismName="+po;
```

po (string) is the user input fetched from my index.jsp form

What is wrong with my sql command?

Comment: I suspect that you are missing quotes around the organism name in the query.  That would be fixed if you used parameterized queries.  Or, you would notice the error if you checked for errors when you run the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying the wrong way. This is the correct way of query with JOIN.

```
"SELECT *
  FROM protein P
INNER JOIN protein_organism PO
  ON PO.pdb_id = P.pdb_id
LEFT JOIN organism O
  ON O.org_id = PO.org_id
WHERE O.organismName="+po;
```

Make appropriate changes to this query if you have some error or different result when run it.